# Making custom pets

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need to make custom pets that I can build in my server, is there a way to do that? I tried to use a wolf and it works but I want to BUILD my pet, is there a way to like shrink my build?

Edit: Ok so someone asked me to clarify my question,
My question is that is there a way to make my build shrink with a command or do I need a plugin, cuz I’m on bedrock on my IPad

Comment: Umm… I don't understand any part of this question. Can you please clarify it a lot?

Comment: I still don't understand, even after your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite vague, but from what I'm understanding, no. There is no way to use a command to make a build smaller. There are mods out there that have custom pets, if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, Idk if I can get mods on pe 